# Solving Partial Differential Equation with separation of variables.

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I have been given this question as an assignment [image]

So far I have made a start solving one of the possible solutions and have made it this far. [image]

My question may seem simple but am I right so far? If so how do I solve for the constants D and E?

Comment: Note that $u(0,t)=0$ for all $t$, so if $A+B\neq 0$ we must have ...

Comment: @user10354138 Sorry I am really trying to understand the direction you are trying to push me in but I am struggling. You're saying that at the point x = 0, u = 0 for all of time I understand that. Now if A+B≠0 then that means De^(kct)+Ee^(-kct) must = 0 right?

Comment: ... for all $t$.

Comment: @user10354138 does this mean it is a trivial solution because t = 0 for all time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to care about the $T(t)$ part of the solution. The boundary conditions are true for *all* $t$, so you necessarily have

\begin{array}{rrr} u(0,t) = X(0)T(t) = 0 &\implies & X(0)=0 \\ u_x(1,t) = X'(1)T(t) = 0 &\implies & X'(1) = 0 \end{array}

Since the only way for a function of $t$ to be zero for all $t$ is if it's zero everywhere, $T(t)\equiv 0$, which we don't want.

Now go through the 3 possible options for $X(x)$ and check whether there exists a non-zero pair $(A,B)$ that can satisfy both conditions.

**Example:** The second option is $X(x) = Ax+B$ which gives

\begin{align} X(0) = B &= 0 \\ X'(1) = A &= 0 \end{align}

Clearly, the only solution is $A=B=0$. Therefore, this can't be a solution.

**Note:** This solution need not be unique. One of the remaining options will leave you with a free constant. This is fine as long as the solution isn't identically zero.

**Spoilers:**

1)

> $X(0) = A + B = 0 \implies B = -A \implies X(x) = A(e^{kx}-e^{-kx})$. Then, $X'(1) = kA(e^k + e^{-k}) = 0$. This only works if $k=0$ or $A=0$, both of which result in $X(x)\equiv 0$. Hence, this can't be a solution.

3)

> $X(0)=A=0 \implies X(x) = B\sin(kx)$. Then, $X'(1) = kB\cos(k) = 0$. This is valid for $B\ne 0$ if you select $k$ such that $\cos(k)=0$, or $k=(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: Thank you for the help Dylan, you explained it in a way that I was actually able to understand unlike my math teacher. One last question, could you please check over this ( https://imgur.com/SE3BeJv ) to make sure I am right (Is this the whole solution)? Also am I even supposed to ask these types of questions on this forum?

Comment: @Asyu7 That's the same image in your post?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, check again

Comment: First time using all this forum type stuff

Comment: Sorry, ( https://imgur.com/TZK99Rr ) is meant to be the link

Comment: @Asyu7 It's correct but you need to put the $T(t)$ part back into the final form of $u(x,t)$

Comment: Sorry I'm confused, I thought you said we don't care about the T(t) part as it was 0 for all time

Comment: @Asyu7 Only the *boundary* is $0$ for all time. You still need time in the full solution.